# How do I make my USB Bluetooth dongle work? (Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110))

Tags: bluetooth

I have a USB bluetooth dongle:

```
root@maiko-cce-lin:~# lsusb | grep Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

It rarely works, and when I do get it to work it stops working when I reboot.

It isn't software blocked:

```
root@maiko-cce-lin:~# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

My device is recognized by `hciconfig`

```
root@maiko-cce-lin:~# hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1F:81:00:01:1C  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 180:1
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:330 acl:0 sco:0 events:8 errors:0
    TX bytes:24 acl:0 sco:0 commands:30 errors:22
    Features: 0xff 0x3e 0x09 0x76 0x80 0x01 0x00 0x80
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

but I can't turn on my hci interface:

```
root@maiko-cce-lin:~# hciconfig hci up
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

I don't understand why; the `hcitool` command doesn't show any devices:

```
root@maiko-cce-lin:~# hcitool dev
Devices:
```

I've tried to restart my bluetooth service too with this command (and then repeated all the previous commands again) but it didn't work:

```
root@maiko-cce-lin:~# service bluetooth restart
 * Stopping bluetooth                                                    [ OK ] 
 * Starting bluetooth                                                    [ OK ] 
root@maiko-cce-lin:~#
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is the dongle supported?

Comment: I think it is. You can be sure here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup#Manual Discovery it's the same device that I have.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe looks like [this reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/268502).

Comment: it looks similar but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I just had these same symptoms with the same model dongle. However, it seemed to resolve immediately when I moved the dongle from a USB hub to a direct USB port on the computer. If you're having the same problem then maybe try that.

#### My symptoms in detail:

Each time the dongle was plugged in I got entries in /var/log/syslog like this:

```
Sep  7 10:05:20 gus-workstation bluetoothd[18537]: Listening for HCI events on hci0
Sep  7 10:05:20 gus-workstation NetworkManager[837]: <warn> bluez error  getting default adapter: No such adapter
Sep  7 10:05:30 gus-workstation bluetoothd[18538]: Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

Mine also showed in hciconfig & no amount of restarts or replugs made a difference.

Also weirdly, I can't reproduce the problem now that the dongle has been paired to something (if I put it back in the hub port now, it now works fine.)

Hth.

Comment: I'm not using a USB hub =| but thx for the answer.

Comment: OK, one more! The "no hub" fix didn't keep working for me, it stopped working as soon as I power cycled the machine. However, I was previously running Ubuntu Maverick (bluez 4.69.) Did a dist-upgrade to Natty (kernel 2.6.38-11, bluez 4.91) and now it works fine. :/

Answer (score 1):

Do the following and it will be fixed.

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

then

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Afterwards check to see if it is running using

```
hciconfig
```

It works every time for me

Comment: Can this be traced using syslogs? Where are they located? I see the device moving from `DOWN` to `DOWN INIT RUNNING`, but then seems to fail and reverts to `DOWN` with no other information